# Capture events from Bluetooth Headset (press button on headset)

Tags: c#, winapi, bluetooth

My app need to capture press button event on headset (connect over Bluetooth). Currently, I got MAC address by using `BluetoothFindFirstDevice()`, `BluetoothFindFirstDevice()` function in winapi. But I cannot find out the way to capture events like press button on headset

Comment: You can investigate the Windows Core Audio APIs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/about-the-windows-core-audio-apis

Comment: HFP profile defines RFCOMM control channel for such things. So you can simple connect to that control channel and receive all the events you need.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko  Can I use WinSock2 to receive that events?

Comment: Yes, you can use WinSock Bluetooth API. Or you may try Bluetooth Framework that makes it much simple. Also take a look on HFP spec to find out the commands: https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=489628

Comment: thanks @MikePetrichenko, I tried Bluetooth Framework for some devices, I run RfcomClient Demo, it work with Galaxy Bud Pro and don't work with Jabra 710, Jabra Talk 5, BeastX,

Comment: It is because by default the demo app connects to SerialPort Profile. You have to change service UUID in the demo code so it connects to HFP service instead. (https://www.btframework.com/rfcomm.htm)

Comment: Some thing is very strange, I check in Computer Management>Device Manager>Bluetooth; and see Service GUID of Galaxy Bud Pro is AVRemoteControlServiceClass_UUID {0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}, but your demo is: wclRfCommClient.SetService(SerialPortServiceClass_UUID); and it still work? If I set wclRfCommClient.SetService(AVRemoteControlServiceClass_UUID), it will cannot connect. Are there something wrong here?

Comment: AVRCP is not RFCOMM based service. It is L2CAP baed service and can not be used directly from windows except you installs it as device. AVRCP, after installation, can be access trhough Multimedia API (unfortunately I used it a long time ago and do not remember all the details).

Comment: very thanks @Mike Petrichenko